# Modify vpn-secrets with nmcli

Tags: networkmanager, nmcli

I'm trying to modify `[vpn-secrets]`, as mentioned here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/198136/error-when-trying-to-connect-to-vpn-on-startup

However, nmcli complains about it,

```
%> sudo nmcli con modify myvpn vpn-secrets.data 'password = xxx'
Error: invalid or not allowed setting 'vpn-secrets': 'vpn-secrets' not among [connection, vpn, ipv4, ipv6].
```

Is it impossible to change the password with nmcli?

Comment: What type of VPN are you attempting to connect to? Only certain VPN plugins may allow the credentials to be set this way. Others require a separate file eg `/etc/ppp/chat-secrets` or `/etc/ipsec.secrets` or `/etc/ipsec.d/some-connection-id.secrets`.

Comment: @dragon788 SSTP